# Delete single punctuation using regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string

I have punctuation that joins the word and doesn't join the word. I want to delete some punctuation that I don't think is necessary

```py
sentence = "@alham sedang bermain @brenx main #gantipresiden dan makan-makan? #"
```

I want sentence same like this:

```
@alham sedang bermain @brenx main #gantipresiden dan makan-makan?
```

you can see my code this it :
https://regex101.com/r/ByqWrH/1

Comment: Can you add the pattern that you tried to the question instead of only the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove `#` where there is not a non whitespace character `\S` before and after, you could use [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<!\S)#(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/N26n2d/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/NvrYbh)

For example:

```
import re

sentence = "@alham sedang bermain @brenx main #gantipresiden dan makan-makan? #"
regex = r"(?<!\S)#(?!\S)"
sentence = re.sub(regex, "", sentence)
print(sentence)
```

Result

> @alham sedang bermain @brenx main #gantipresiden dan makan-makan?

Answer (score 0):

Try matching `# ... #` and then replace without the closing `#` tag:

```
sentence = "@alham sedang bermain @brenx main #gantipresiden dan makan-makan? #"
output = re.sub(r'#([^#]+?)[ ]*#', '#\\1', sentence)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
@alham sedang bermain @brenx main #gantipresiden dan makan-makan?
```